# Is it possible to add other font styles for default monospace font?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, fonts

I've changed the default Droid Sans Mono to Roboto Mono by replacing the font file, keeping the filename. Can I add other font styles to it (bold, italic, bold-italic)? Will the OS detect and use them instead of synthetically creating them?